# Melexis sensors how to get PWM output?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect, configuration

The Melexis [MLX90372 datasheet](https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90372/Gen3-Triaxis-Rotary-Linear-Position-Sensor) says that it can output either SENT protocol or **PWM**. I do not see anywhere in the datasheet how to put it into "**PWM Mode**" as they call it.  Nor do I see how to configure the PWM frequency 100Hz-2kHz.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Ah, let me skim the friendly datasheet. Page 45 - "Output config: protocol" tells you how to do ti.

Comment: And what you want is PSF, no DIY.

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes, I've seen section 12.  I guess what isn't clear to me is, do I have to use SENT protocol to configure it?  Seems silly to implement SENT just to configure PWM, might as well use SENT at that point.

Comment: Ah, I am just wildly guessing: (1)  This device is for mass production manufacturers, ie, who produce perhaps one million cars per month. So they don't program or reprogram  the device themselves. All PSF (Product Specific Functions) are decided before they place the huge quantity order. In other words, each device arrived is either SENT or PWM, and all the other PSFs are not changeable after they arrive. (2) SENT is a very misleading term. It mean what is "sent" by the device out to the CAN or MCU etc. In other words, it is unidirectional - output only. / to continue, ...

Comment: Yes, their is the "input" pin, but I think you need to order one million pieces to ask for Melxis to tailor made something according to your specific spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out these are programmed via a chip programmer, like an eeprom or micro-controller.  Melexis make the [PTC-04](https://www.melexis.com/en/software-tools/ptc04) for programming their chips.